# Apply Texture and Also shadow to an image with Canvas Javascript

Tags: html, css, canvas

I want to create objects on canvas with textures, textures like paper, cloth.
and i want to place the image. and the image should follow the texture.

I do not know what to use, is it possible to use a canvas? When I use [Teespring](https://teespring.com/design-launcher/design/product_bb2a) they can make images follow textures .. but I guess they do not use canvas for product preview. they only provide image response generated from serverside ...

[image]

[image]

**Current result**

Now i just can make preview logo on a product only on flat surfaces.. the problem is the logo preview should also be on object like mug, tshirt, bottle and tshirt

[image]

Comment: The canvas 2D API has many composite operations. You can use one or more of them in combination with `globalAlpha` to get the FX that suits your needs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation

Comment: If you want distortion, then only webgl will give you that.